# Use Cauchy Theorem to prove that every element in a group $G$ is a $k$-th root iff $(k,|G|)=1$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

> Every element of a finite group $G$ has a $k$-th root if and only if $(k,|G|)= 1$.

I want to prove this proposition, I´m trying to use this function that for all g in G , g will send it to $g^k$ and then use the Cauchy Theorems but i need help please and I do not know how to apply the theorem.

Comment: The idea is that you have a map from $G$ to $G$ (**not** a homomorphism, just a set map).  Since $G$ is finite, being surjective is the same as being injective.  Now think about primes dividing $k$ and $|G|$...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If every element of $G$ has a $k$-th root then $\phi:G\to G$ defined by $\phi(g)=g^k$ is a surjective map. Since $G$ is a finite set it follows that $\phi$ is injective and therefore if $g\in G$ is such that $g^k=e$ it follows $g=e.$ Now let $p\mid k$ and $p\mid |G|$ a prime number. From Cauchy's Theorem there exists $x\in G$ of order $p$. In particular, $x^p=e$. Rising this to the $(k/p)^{th}$ power we get $x^k=e$, so $x=e$, a contradiction.

If $(k,|G|)=1$ then there exist $u,v\in\mathbb Z$ such that $ku+|G|v=1$, and thus $g=(g^u)^k$ for every $g\in G$.